# Place a non-wrapping element after a wrapping text

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic text, after which I want to in-line place a button. To make it responsive I want the text to wrap, but I do not want the button to wrap "on its own". So it should always wrap with at least the last word of the text.

This is my minimal example:
https://jsfiddle.net/emckab7q/

```css
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  white-space: normal;
}

button {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<span class="wrapper">
  <span class="text">This is some text of unknown length that can get quite long and thus may wrap</span><button></button>
</span>
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image: what it looks like]

I want it to look like this:

[image: What it should look like]

**Since the text is dynamic I cannot just place the button inside the text and "no-wrap" it with the last word.**

Comment: Not possible with CSS without structural changes to your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

negtive margin combined with padding can do it:

```css
.text {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding-right:24px;
}

button {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  margin-left:-24px; /* same as padding */
}
```

```html
<span class="wrapper">
  <span class="text">This is some text of unknown length that can get quite long and thus may wrap</span><button></button>
</span>
```